# MySQL Where on Multiple Left Join Rows

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause

I have a MySQL Left Join Query that returns 1 row from table A and multiple rows from table B. I need to have multiple WHERE clauses on these rows and only return if all of the B rows match.

I have:

```
SELECT 

mage_sales_order.entity_id

FROM mage_sales_order 

LEFT JOIN mage_sales_order_item 
ON mage_sales_order.entity_id = mage_sales_order_item.order_id 

WHERE 

 mage_sales_order_item.sku NOT LIKE '1-%' 
 AND mage_sales_order_item.sku LIKE '2-%' 

 ## Group order IDs together 
 GROUP BY entity_id
```

However this will return any order that has an item with the SKU starting with "2-" even if it has an item starting with "1-". I want it so that orders only with items starting with "2-" are returned.

For example:

Should be returned:

- Order 1 (mage_sales_order)

  - 2-sampleA-sku (mage_sales_order_item)
  - 2-sampleB-sku (mage_sales_order_item)

Should not be returned:

- Order 1 (mage_sales_order)

  - 1-sample-sku (mage_sales_order_item)
  - 2-sampleA-sku (mage_sales_order_item)
  - 2-sampleB-sku (mage_sales_order_item)

I assume this has already been asked but trying to search for it is proving difficult.

Comment: Why the `AND` before the `mage_sales_order_item.sku NOT LIKE '1-%' ` ?

Comment: @KaushikNP Because I simplified the sql for this question and forgot to remove it (edited now)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another sub query to exclude those rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT mage_sales_order.entity_id
FROM mage_sales_order 
LEFT JOIN mage_sales_order_item 
ON mage_sales_order.entity_id = mage_sales_order_item.order_id 
WHERE mage_sales_order_item.sku LIKE '2-%' 
AND mage_sales_order_item.order_id NOT IN (
    SELECT order_id FROM mage_sales_order_item WHERE sku LIKE '1-%'
)
GROUP BY entity_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the logic in the `WHERE` clause to a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    t1.entity_id
FROM mage_sales_order t1
LEFT JOIN mage_sales_order_item t2
    ON t1.entity_id = t2.order_id
GROUP BY
    t1.entity_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.sku NOT LIKE '2-%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The logical problem with your current `WHERE` clause is that this logic gets applied to individual records.  It makes no sense that say that the SKU should start with `2-` and also not start with `1-`, since the former condition already guarantees the latter.  But, taken in the context of an aggregation over entities, the logic does seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the conditions from the `WHERE` clause into the `JOIN` :

```
SELECT mage_sales_order.entity_id
FROM mage_sales_order 
LEFT JOIN mage_sales_order_item 
ON 
   mage_sales_order.entity_id = mage_sales_order_item.order_id 
   AND mage_sales_order_item.sku NOT LIKE '1-%' 
   AND mage_sales_order_item.sku LIKE '2-%' 
WHERE mage_sales_order_item.order_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY entity_id
```

Comment: If the SKU starts with `2-` then by definition it can't also start with `1-`, so at the very least you could remove one of your join conditions.